# preg_match with ' and ñ

Tags: php

i want a text that only accept letters upper/lower, accents (Á,á,É,é,Í,í,Ó,ó,Ú,ú) and character spain 'ñ,Ñ'

```
if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", $_POST["text"]))
    $er = "Introduce un nombre válido";
```

Where i must put this charácter?

```
if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z][Á,á,É,é,Í,í,Ó,ó,Ú,ú][ñ]/", $_POST["text"]))
    $er = "Introduce un nombre válido";
```

This doesnt work, where is the wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this match.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-ZÁáÉéÍíÓóÚúñ]+$/", $_POST["text"]))
    $er = "Introduce un nombre válido";
```

regex one [ ] expression is one group.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn work, for example if i put 'holaaaa6666' function said me that it only has letters

Comment: i fixed my answer. but I can't read spanish. if $er is not error message. maybe you can remove ! sign.

Comment: ^and scape +$. Fix. Many thanks!!